# Simple wikipedia library that returns link list is not behaving as expected

Tags: python, wikipedia

I'm using `pip install wikipedia` to make a simple ["Philosophy step counter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy) and can't get the result I'm looking for. No matter what page I enter the code never finds a link that matches any of the words in the first few sentences of the article. Code is below:

```
import os
import string
import wikipedia

wikipedia.set_lang("en")

print("Please type the name of a wikipedia article: ")
page = input()
print("Searching wikipedia for: " + page)
wikiPage = wikipedia.page(page)
print("Using top result: " + wikiPage.title)

# currentPage = wikipedia.page(wikiPage.links[0])

# List of links (sorted alphabetically, makes our job much harder)
links = wikiPage.links

# Split the beginning of the article into words
words = wikipedia.summary(wikiPage, sentences=3).split()

words = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation)
         for s in words]  # Sanitize list of words to remove punctuation

# comparisons = [a == b for (a, b) in itertools.product(words, links)]

x = 0
while words[x] not in links:
    print(words[x])
    x = x + 1

newPage = wikipedia.page(words[x])
```

Is this a fault of the library I'm using or my code? The link list appears to be ordered alphabetically if that makes any difference (hence why I'm doing all this in the first place)

Comment: I've never used that library, but I'll point out that the Philosophy chain was broken awhile ago. Someone edited the Mathamatics page, and it now results in a loop. Mathamatics was one of the main pages that fed to Philosophy, so it doesn't work any more for the most part.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I had no idea, that's unfortunate. I'd still like to complete this as a programming exercise though, I hate leaving projects unfinished.

Comment: After looking this over for a few minutes, there's a few problems. The main one however is that `links` includes multi-word link names, whereas `words` are all single words. If you try "Amado Boudou" (he was on the wiki homepage), his first link is "Vice President of Argentina", but you've split those into multiple words, so that won't be found.

Comment: Also, links will probably be title-cased which is not how they appear in sentences in the most cases.